# jQuery: Recursive call of local function does not work

Tags: jquery, function, recursion, local

I've tried using Google to solve my problem but I didn't find the solution. I've written a small jQuery-script that slides two div-containers up and down independantly. To repeat this sliding endlessley I used a recursive call. This is my code:

```
jQuery.fn.scroller = function() {
      var scrollamount = $(this).height() - $(window).height();
      var scrollduration = scrollamount * 10;
      var pauseduration = 3000;
      var docheight = $(this).height();
      var doScroll = function () {
          $(this).delay(pauseduration)
              .animate({top: -scrollamount, height: docheight}, scrollduration, 'linear')
              .delay(pauseduration)
              .animate({top: 0, height: $(window).height()}, scrollduration, 'linear', $(this).doScroll);

          };
      $(this).height($(window).height()).doScroll();
      };
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#globdiv').scroller();
    $('#globdiv2').scroller();
    });
```

Error console indicates that doScroll in this line

```
$(this).height($(window).height()).doScroll();
```

is not a function.
I found an alternative solution:

```
$.fn.doScroll = function(pauseduration, scrollamount, scrollduration, docheight) {
          $(this).delay(pauseduration)
              .animate({top: -scrollamount, height: docheight}, scrollduration, 'linear')
              .delay(pauseduration)
              .animate({top: 0, height: $(window).height()}, scrollduration, 'linear', function(){
                  $(this).doScroll(pauseduration, scrollamount, scrollduration, docheight);
              });
     };
$.fn.scroller = function(){
      var scrollamount = $(this).height() - $(window).height();
      var scrollduration = scrollamount * 10;
      var pauseduration = 3000;
      var docheight = $(this).height();
      $(this).height($(window).height()).doScroll(pauseduration, scrollamount, scrollduration, docheight);
      };
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#globdiv').scroller();
    $('#globdiv2').scroller();
    });
```

which works fine, but I would like to learn why my first approach does not work and what I can do to make it run.
Best regards - Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

You first approach doesnt work because `doScroll` is not a method on the `jQuery` object, its just a local function. You could make it work like this though:

```
doScroll.apply($(this).height($(window).height()));
```

Or you could change the signature of doScroll to accept the element/jQuery object as an argument:

```
var doScroll = function (ele) {
          $(ele).delay(pauseduration)
              .animate({top: -scrollamount, height: docheight}, scrollduration, 'linear')
              .delay(pauseduration)
              .animate({top: 0, height: $(window).height()}, scrollduration, 'linear', function (){doScroll(ele);})};

          };
          doScroll($(ele).height($(window).height()));
      };
```

Comment: Hallo prodigitalson,
first I thought that ronnyfm's proposal seemed to be more simple and straight forward, but what I figured out at last seems to match your proposal exactly. Thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 0):

Function .doScroll isn't available for $(this) but to "this", that's why chaining doesn't work, try this:

```
$(this).height($(window).height());
this.doScroll();
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint, but unfortunately it doesn' work. Error console still reports "this.doScroll is not a function"

Comment: The forum software didn't allow me to post the new code. It says "too long". Hewever you can see the script in action here: http://www.ulrichbangert.de/div/webdesign/javascript/scroll2divs2.html

Comment: Now I've figured out a solution that is working: I omitted the this, when calling cScroll() and handed over the jQuery-Object:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/div/webdesign/javascript/scroll2divs2.html

Comment: Yes, I saw my mistake, passing the object was the solution as $(this) inside of doScroll function was in another context.